# Force Scroll to Top - Ionic

Tags: jquery, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am showing a custom list rendered with data coming from external server.
this is my page. 
There are two buttons left and right at bottom. I want that when user clicks Back or Forward button (to load more data) he goes to top of page. I have tried $ionicScrollDelegate.scrollTop();
already and it's not working. Here's my code:

```
<ion-content scroll="false">
        <div id="content" class="snap-content" style="height:700px;">
            <div class="content">
            <div class="header-clear-large"></div>
            <!--Page content goes here, fixed elements go above the all elements class-->

                <!--ALL THE LISTS ARE HERE -->

                <div class="footer">
                    <span class="fl"><i class="fa fa-angle-left fa-3x fl"  ng-click="loadPrev()"  ng-if="page_arrow == 1 && start_list > 0"></i></span>
                    <span class="fr"><i class="fa fa-angle-right fa-3x fr"  ng-click="loadMore()"  ng-if="page_arrow == 1"></i></span>
                </div>

            <!-- End of entire page content-->
            </div> 
        </div>

    </ion-content>
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you have a function in the .js part like this?

```
function MainCtrl($scope, $ionicScrollDelegate) {
  $scope.loadMore = function() {
    $ionicScrollDelegate.scrollTop();
  };
}
```

You said that you tried 'ionicScrollDelegate' but whitout the js part, it's not possible to guess what's causing your problem.

There is a simple guide: http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/service/$ionicScrollDelegate/